# Convert Django Queryset to list or dict

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary, django-queryset

From my views.py I doing this query:

```
var_query = DB.objects.filter(Q(user_id=str(request.user.id)) & Q(router_name='router1'  )).values('router_type',  'router_ip')
```

Working because I get this result:

```
{'router1': set(['[{"router_type": "CISCO", "router_ip": "192.168.1.1"}]'])}
```

the type of var_query is: `<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>`

When I convert this with list()

`converted = list(var_query)`

and  this error: 
`AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'iteritems'`

becasue when a convert this queryset to list is inserted this: set(['

How to convert to real list or dict so I can work with my key or value?

Comment: have you tried values_list function?

Comment: The original code does not give you what you claim. You have some code which you have not posted which is converting it to a dictionary of sets, for some reason.

Comment: If I use .value_list I only gest the values and not key:value. This Is the reason and the "set(['   is always inserted in the list.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what your final aim is. But it seems like you are overcomplicating things unnecessarily. I would suggest simplifying your approach and just filter the queryset normally (note, it looks like these `Q` objects are also unnecessary here, you can just pass the args in directly).

```
var_query = DB.objects.filter(
    Q(user_id=str(request.user.id)) & Q(router_name='router1')
)
```

The result will be a queryset object that implements the iterator protocol and can be iterated over normally like a list or list-like object. Then to work with the fields in the data that you seem to be interested in, you can just do something like:

```
var_query = DB.objects.filter(
    Q(user_id=str(request.user.id)) & Q(router_name='router1')
)

for obj in var_query:
    router_type = obj.router_type
    router_ip = obj.router_ip
    # ... do other stuff with your data.
```

You don't need to bother using `values` unless you really have a proper use case for it.

If you can supply more context we can refine a more accurate solution.